# Exception on orientation change from two-pane mode to one-pane mode

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have a demo app which supports both smartphones and tablets.

Also it supports orientation change.

On tablets there is one pane and two pane modes. Two pane modes works only in landscape mode. All UI is exposed into fragments.

UI in two pane mode is common master-detail pattern: list on the left and detail screen on the right.

**All the rest is related to tablets when it in landscape mode.**

The scenario:

1. Run app on tablet in landscape mode
2. Select the article on the left (on second pane default fragment will be replace by fragment with article details)
3. Change orientation
4. Exception appears

The issue I face with is when orientation change happens I receive an exception. The error message reports there is no FrameLayout with id details - this one is related to layout which should be shown only for `layout-sw600dp-land`. For portrait mode there is another layout `layout-sw600dp-port`

The business logic is explecitly checks the current mode and there is no operations within `FragmentManager` on `R.id.details`

```
public void show() {
    if (isTwoPaneMode()) {
        showMain();
        showDetailed();
    } else {
        showMain();
    }
}
```

It brings me to the thought is there any hidden transaction on this `R.id.details` that doesn't exist for this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in setRetainInstance(true) in detailed fragment (it was missed due refactoring).

When it was removed everything starts work well.